# Is it a problem to turn off power to a running QSerialPort?

Tags: windows, qt, asynchronous, segmentation-fault, serial-port

I'm developing an application with several serial ports. Each of these ports is handled by a different thread and has its own `QSerialPort` object. From a hardware point of view, they are connected hierarchicaly, meaning that there is one main device connected to the PC with a usb cable (1 COM port), to this main device there are several other devices connected, each of them having its own COM port. The main device can turn on/off the power supply to these child ports.

In the application, the ports are handled asynchronously. Each device object is running in its own loop. If its port is opened, it reads the incoming data. If the port is closed, it tries to open it in every loop until it succeeds. Each `QSerialPort` object handles errors on the `errorOccurred` signal. If it receives `DeviceNotFoundError`, `PermissionError`, `ResourceError` error, the port is closed (if it was opened) and the looping continues as described above.

The problem is that this serial communication part of the application is crashing (segmentation fault). I spent days finding the issue but with no results so far. To better understand what is going on, I wanted to ask here. Could it be a problem for `QSerialPort` if the main device turns off the power supply for the child ports while they're opened and are working? Or if the power supply is turned off while the child ports are being opened/closed or any other operation is being executed on them? (I don't want to include the specific executable code as it's a part of a bigger application and would be hard to make and executable from it. I'd like to discuss just the concepts described above if possible.)

Thanks for any help or ideas!

UPDATE

Creating of `QSerialPort` and putting it into a different thread:

```
QThread *t = new QThread(this)
SomeObject *o = new SomeObject(this);

o->moveToThread(t);
t->start();
```

Later in the `SomeObject`:

```
QSerialPort *port = new QSerialPort();
```

Comment: Could you add your code where the segmentation fault occurs please?

Comment: @ElevenJune I don't know where it occurs. That's why I'm speaking just abstractly with no code example.

Comment: Could you show the part where you create the QSerialPort and put them into different threads ?

Comment: @ElevenJune Updated the question.

Comment: Are your SomeObject* and QSerialPort* in the same thread ?
This is my code : 
   `m_serialPort = new QSerialPort();
    m_serialPortThread = new QThread();

    m_serialPort->moveToThread(m_serialPortThread);
    moveToThread(m_serialPortThread);
    m_serialPortThread->start();`
My SomeObject* creates the QThread and moves itself in it with its QSerialPort.

Comment: The whole routine is following: SomeObject has its own thread and QSerialPort pointer. Then there is AnotherObject from another thread, which accesses SomeObject's pointer, creates and opens the QSerialPort object. Then only AnotherObject works with the port, so the port is created and handled by the same thread. This implementation had its reasons and it's not standard. It works fine, but sometimes it accidentaly crashes in some part of serial communication.

Comment: @T.Poe, did you ever figure out a solution to this?  I have the same problem, if the serial port I have open looses power or is disconnected, I get a segmentation fault, even if I try to close the port as soon as it's detected.  I would appreciate it if you could share your solution (if you found one yet).  Thanks!

Comment: @Brent I'm not sure if we solved the issue or it just stopped happening. Here is a thread I started on qt forum, maybe something of that helps you: https://forum.qt.io/topic/94878/turning-off-power-to-a-running-qserialport

Answer (score 0):

Try to destroy port object before power off, and recreate it after power on

```
QSerialPort *port = new QSerialPort();
//init and use
//....
delete port;
port = nullptr;
//turn the power off

//turn the power on
port = new QSerialPort();
```

Comment: The problem is, that switching on and off the ports is asynchronous. I don't know when it happens, so I cannot destroy the object.